# Why doesn't this string concatenation formatting work?

Tags: python

```py
code = "+"
message = "{} " + code + "{} = {}".format('1', '2', '3')

print(message)
```

I supposed this should print `1+2=3`, but actually it print out:

```
{} +1 = 2
```

Why is that? This should the same as:

`message = "{} + {} = {}".format('1', '2', '3')`, in which case it work as expected.

Comment: Why is this surprising? You're only formatting the second string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format function here is being called on the "{}={}" string and not on the whole message string and therefore "{}" before + is printed as it is.
To correct this simply change the message line to

```
message = ("{} " + code + "{} = {}").format('1', '2', '3')
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the `format` method is only applied to the last string within the double quotes e.g. `"{} = {}"`.

If you want the whole string result, you should call the `format` method on only one string:

```
message = "{0} {1} {2} = {3}".format('1', code, '2', '3')
print(message)
# '1 + 2 = 3'
```

Have a look at this [page](https://pyformat.info/), it is really useful for string formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The `.format('1', '2', '3')` is being applied to the last string in the concatenation (`"{} = {}"`), not the entire thing. Putting parenthesis around the concatenation and adding the `.format()` to that and it should produce the results you expect.

Answer (score 1):

What the above people said is correct. You could do something like this

```
def createMessage(a,b ,c):
    code = '+'
    mes1 = "{}".format(a)
    mes2 = "{} = {}".format(b,c)
    message = mes1 + code + mes2
    print(message)


createMessage(1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the format applies only to the last chars between the double quotes (`"{} = {}"`). So, the number three is simply discarded and the code variable is replaced with its value.

Answer (score 0):

```py
code = "+"
message = ("{} " + code + "{} = {}").format('1', '2', '3')
print(message)
```

Above code should work. This is because, first "{}" is considered as a separate string, 
**"{} = {}".format('1', '2', '3')** is only evaluated for the format. 
Hence the wrong output